# Will installing Chrome on Ubuntu do anything to Chrome on Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, google-chrome

I have a dual boot computer(Ubuntu, Windows 7, both 64-bit).

I installed Chrome on Ubuntu, and since that, my dad says Chrome on Windows is slower/internet doesn't work/other stuff similar to them.

I have an eMachines E1331G.

Will installing programs on Ubuntu do anything to programs on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't. Think of Ubuntu and windows as 2 different people in a room. They know nothing of each other. Except that you can mount windows drive with Ubuntu but that doesn't mean it will affect windows unless you personally do something on the drive.

Answer (score 1):

No, because Windows can't write to Ubuntu's formatted disks (usually ext[2|3|4]) because it doesn't have the appropriate drivers (unless you use something like [ext2fs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/ext2.html)).
However, if you sign in the same Google Account on both Chrome(/Chromium) installations, settings, bookmarks, passwords etc. will be synced.

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't, as Windows cannot open the Ubuntu partition (by default). Something else is slowing down Windows. You can try clearing browser data on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

No, with an Ubuntu installation the windows partition is untouched other than the boot, and unless you specifically mount the windows drive and go into the program files folder & set up a little virus your ubuntu installation will leave your windows partition alone, as long as you don't manually mess stuff up it won't mess itself up...at least when running ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

The two programs won't interact, and certainly at the operating system level, the answer is a resounding 'no.

But...

If you have signed into Google Chrome using the same account in both operating systems, then your instances of Chrome will do helpful things like synchronize plugins, bookmarks, and some settings. This still shouldn't cause your dad to experience any slowness, but it *does* mean that there are cross-platform effects.